# Python how to get self from class function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, self

Can I get self from class function? For example:

```
class abc:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
  def printname(self):
    print(self.name)

x = abc("test").printname()
```

I want to get original class obj `abc("test")` from `x` without using return self or define `x = abc("test")` at first, is it possible?

Comment: There is nothing in `x`, only a `None` value as `printname()` returns nothing. So from a `None` you can do nothing

Comment: Your question includes two perfectly good solutions -- one is to have `printname` return the object, the other is to assign `x` to the object directly.  What's wrong with either of those?

Comment: I want to emphasize what @azro said, your `x` value stores `None` because your function doesn't return anything. Therefore it will be impossible to obtain the class. If you would use `abs('test').printname`, (note the lack of closing brackets, so we are not calling the function) you can get the class using. `x.__self__`.

Comment: "I want to achieve something without using the trivial and only ways to achieve it, can I ?" that's what your question looks like to us, do you get it ?

Comment: @Samwise  this is an example

Comment: What's it an example of?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer:

1. `printname` is not a "class function", it's an *instance method*.  A *class* method is one that takes the class as the first parameter.  Most methods are *instance* methods; they take `self` (a particular instance of the class) as the first parameter.  If this were indeed a class method, there would be no "self" associated with it.
2. The thing you're referring to as a "class object" is an *instance* of the class `abc`.  `abc` is itself an object (everything in Python is an object, including class definitions), but that's not the same thing as the instance you get by calling `abc("test")`.
3. Any time you want to take a value that's local to a particular function call and make it available to the caller (including its parameters), you need to `return` it.  There are technically other tricks involving mutating state in the caller's scope, but those aren't applicable to your example.  If you ended `printname` with the line `return self`, then doing `x = abc("test").printname()` would result in the instance being assigned to `x`.
4. In your example, the caller is the one that constructs the instance, so simply writing this would also do the trick:

```
x = abc("test")
x.printname()
```